# Declare a variable from the same type as an instance of that template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a container template,

```
template <typename T, typename S>
class Container
{
    public:
       S size(void) const { return mItems; }

    private:
       S mItems;
       S mMaxItems;
       T *mArray;
};
```

And in the code I would like to do this:

```
Container<Rooms, int> RoomCtr;

for(RoomCtr::type i = 0; i < RoomCtr.size(); i++)
{
}
```

so that the variable matches the `S` type without me specifying the `int` hardcoded.

Is this possible?

The only way I found so far is this:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
class Container
{
    S type(void) const { return 0; }
    ...
};


for(decltype(Table.type()) i = 0; i < RoomCtr.size(); i++)
{
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way. Or would this be the correct way to do it?

I'm using currently Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What is `Rooms`? The size of the container?

Comment: Note that the `type()` function doesn't have to be defined if it's only to be used in unevaluated contexts, as `decltype`'s operand is.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use decltype.    Either as you are or, if `Container` contains `typedef S Type;` as `decltype(Table)::Type`.     This is probably the closest you'll get to introspection.

Comment: @Peter, is that `decltype(Table)::Type` syntax a C11 feature? Because in VS2010 I get an error when I try it this way, though I would perfer this one. "type is no element of global namespace"

Comment: @Devolus You mean a C++11 feature? `decltype` is C++11.

Comment: Yes, `decltype` is a C++11 feature.    AFAIK, VS2010 supported part of what (later came to be) standard in C++11 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typedef in combination with decltype:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <typename T, typename S>
class Container
{
    public:
       typedef S SomeType;
       S size(void) const { return mItems; }

    private:
       S mItems;
       S mMaxItems;
};

struct A
{
    //empty
};
int main()
{
    Container<A, int> roomCtr;
    decltype(roomCtr)::SomeType j = 0;   
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This works (even though it doesn't work for VS2010 but that's a different issue :) ).

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple `typedef`:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
class Container {
  T *data;
  /* other variables */

  public:
    typedef S size_type;
    Container();

};

int main() {
  Container<char, int>::size_type something;
}
```

Here `something` will be of type `int`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because here it doesn't use the existing instance of a variable. Instead I have to retype the full template definition, which I would avoid with the decltype. Additionally, if I decide to change the int to short, then `something` would be of the wrong type. because it is not associated with the instance.

Comment: @Devolus What's wrong with just doing `decltype(RoomCtr)::size_type` in that case?

Comment: Well, this is how [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) does it. Also, if you want to use an existing instance, you'd need a member function, that _returns a type, not an instance of this type_, which is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: @TartanLlama, my first version looked uglier because I was "abusing" the method `size()` just to get the type. I changed that now (as I posted above) and added a dummy function named `type` which makes the intention clearer. `decltype(Table.size())` to get the type didn't feel right, so I wanted a better solution, which I found now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use typedefs to solve your problem. 
E.g.:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <typename T, typename S>
class Container
{
    public:
       S size(void) const { return mItems; }

    private:
       S mItems;
       S mMaxItems;
};

struct A
{
    //empty
};
int main()
{
    typedef int SomeType;
    Container<A, SomeType> RoomCtr;

    for(SomeType i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

}
```

You could also explicitly keep the type in the class with a typedef.
E.g.:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <typename T, typename S>
class Container
{
    public:
        typedef S SomeType;
       S size(void) const { return mItems; }

    private:
       S mItems;
       S mMaxItems;
};

struct A
{
    //empty
};
int main()
{
    typedef int MyType;
    Container<A, MyType> roomCtr;
    Container<A, MyType>::SomeType j = 0;   
    std::cout << j << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Same problem as in the other answer. It doesn't infer the type from the instance variable.